# Enable and disable of Controls not working properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `aspx form` where I want to `Enable` and `Disable`
some controls based on the rights assigned to the resprective Users.

The logic is something like this.

IF Condition matched to `Y` then enable the controls
else The controls should be disabled.

So, I wrote the below code based on condition

```
if (Hid_Mode.Value != "M")
    {
        DataTable dtFill = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM WMS_MENU_RIGHTS WHERE MKEY = '" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + "' and MENU_MKEY = '" + Request.QueryString["menuid"].ToString() + "'", constr);
        sda.Fill(dtFill);

        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            //Disable control
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            //Disable control
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            //Disable control
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            //Disable control
        }
    }

public static void DisableFormControl(ControlCollection ChildCtrls)
{
    foreach (Control Ctrl in ChildCtrls)
    {
        if (Ctrl is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)Ctrl).Enabled = false;
        if (Ctrl is DropDownList)
            ((DropDownList)Ctrl).Enabled = false;
        if (Ctrl is CheckBoxList)
            ((CheckBoxList)Ctrl).Enabled = false;
        if (Ctrl is Button)
            ((Button)Ctrl).Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

But what happening here is

*Even if one condition is FALSE and other three are TRUE, it still disables the whole control.*
I dont know why its happening like this

**UPDATE**

ON Page load I am disabling every control and after that.

```
DisableFormControl(Form.Controls);

    if (Hid_Mode.Value != "M")
    {
        DataTable dtFill = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM WMS_MENU_RIGHTS WHERE MKEY = '" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + "' and MENU_MKEY = '" + Request.QueryString["menuid"].ToString() + "'", constr);
        sda.Fill(dtFill);

        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
            txtdesc.Enabled = true;
            txtadd1.Enabled = true;
            txtadd2.Enabled = true;
            txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
            check_desc.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
            txtdesc.Enabled = true;
            txtadd1.Enabled = true;
            txtadd2.Enabled = true;
            txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
            check_desc.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false;
            txtdesc.Enabled = false;
            txtadd1.Enabled = false;
            txtadd2.Enabled = false;
            txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false;
            check_desc.Enabled = false;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
            txtdesc.Enabled = true;
            txtadd1.Enabled = true;
            txtadd2.Enabled = true;
            txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
            check_desc.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

But still the control is disabled even if condition is true

Comment: Always use parameterized queries to avoid sql-injection attacks! Your code has serious vulnerability.

Comment: @Esko: Thanks for stating that, but any idea on how to deal with this logic ?

Comment: Your example code does not actually call the disable-method so this is not verifiable example. We don't know what you are passing there or see your control hierarchy. I suspect that you disable some parent control and in the process the child control will be disable as well. Or some other related problem to control hierarchy.

Comment: There are couple of things that may be causing the problem, First make sure you get capital Y from record rather small case y. Secondly you are not enabling controls in given code if once disabled. If control is disabled in one case and would be enabled in other case then your logic will keep it disabled because you are not enabling it. Debugging the code would make it easy to find the root cause.

Comment: @Adil, esko: let me try and check with debugging

Comment: @Adil: Not working in my case, see my updates for more info

Comment: It is entering every condition you stated. Probably it is running the last condition statement that it considered true.   Have you tried using `Else if`?

Comment: @Hexxed: Nope I didnt tried that. Can you tell me what will be scenario in that ?

Comment: Are the flags mutually exclusive? Provide us values for all flags like, VIEW_FLAG, DEL_FLAG? and what is the output? and what is expected output?

Comment: @Adil: The values of flags are here with total description https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCDS.png. And What I expect output is, if the flag is `Y` then enabled the controls and if the flag is != `Y ` then disabled the controls

Comment: All controls were set to  `False` because `[VIEW_FLAG]` is set to `Y`. Even if `[ADD_FLAG]` is set to `Y`. The latter gets validated last. I think you have set the `MENU_RIGHTS` with only 1 type of privilege.

Comment: @Hexxed: is something wrong with `MENU_RIGHTS` table. ? Do i need to add some extra logic in the table ?

Comment: @Adil: Any sort of guidance on how to proceed with this ?

Comment: You should be specific what options user can select for flag, can user select any combination of flags?

Comment: @Adil: YES he can select any combination of flags whatever he wants.. IT all depends on the selection

Comment: If a user can have multiple user privileges, you may want to group the controls into the function they will be doing. Eg. `btn1` and `btn2` are for `[ADD_FLAG]` then enable it. Not by disabling/enabling them altogether. However, there are flaws. Eg. `user1` Have `[VIEW_FLAG]` and `[MODIFY_FLAG]` are both set to `Y`. That would be an issue.

Comment: @Hexxed: Sorry, I didn't got you. What exactly shd I do in this case ? **UPDATE** So cant we achieve this ?

Comment: In the code you shown, you are disabling the controls altogether. I'm suggesting you to group the controls according to their function. Like all your `textBoxes` will only be enabled for `[ADD_FLAG]` `[MODIFY_FLAG]` and `[MODIFY_FLAG]`

Comment: @Hexxed: So shd I create `ADD()`, `MODIFY()` and `VIEW()` function and call them whenever it is `Y` ?

Comment: @Adil: Sir, what happen..atleast some logic also will do ?

Comment: @nad What would be output if VIEW_FLAG and DEL_FLAG are selected at a time as both do opposite of each other? I think you have to user somehow to make some option exclusive like view and delete! as they cancel each other.

Comment: @Adil: On this condition only the `delete` button will get enabled with view Logic. Its strange but it is like this only

Comment: Let me add something for you see my answer.

Comment: Sure. Atleast will get some idea.. Waiting for ur answer

Comment: With the example given in the image where `add` and `view` flags are Y and the other flags are N, your code first enables the controls in `if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")`, then disables them again in `if (dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")`

Comment: @user1429080: yes its doing that only and it is not as per my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per setting some *criteria*, I have to check multiple conditions and then assign the `Enabled` and `Disabled` logic.
So before assigning the logic, what I did was created a Matrix for every possible conditions.

Below is the Image of the matrix.

[image]

So considering each matrix in mind, I assigned the functionality like below

```
if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true; btnDelete.Enabled = true; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true; txtadd1.Enabled = true; txtadd2.Enabled = true; txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true; check_desc.Enabled = true; txtdesc.Enabled = true;
        }

        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" && dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() != "Y")
        {
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false; btnDelete.Enabled = false; btnClear.Enabled = true;
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false; txtadd1.Enabled = false; txtadd2.Enabled = false; txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false; check_desc.Enabled = false; txtdesc.Enabled = false;
        }
```

**@All:- Let me know if something is missing or logically incorrect**

Comment: Your matrix does not show how each set of options would enable or disable the controls. If this code is meeting the requirements then you can go for it.

Answer (score 3):

You have overlapping cases what I suggest is to enable all the controls and disable specific control under condition. I think you have to make some option exclusive like view and delete! as they cancel each other. This is something you can try that I made based on discussion with you and you may need to further tune it.

```
txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
txtdesc.Enabled = true;
txtadd1.Enabled = true;
txtadd2.Enabled = true;
txtadd3.Enabled = true;
ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
check_desc.Enabled = true;
btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
btnDelete.Enabled = true;
btnClear.Enabled = true;

if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" || dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
{
    btnDelete.Enabled = false;
}
bool enableAll = false;
if(dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
    enableAll = true;
else
if(dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
    enableAll = false;

if(dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" || dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
{
    txtAbbreviation.Enabled = enableAll;
    txtdesc.Enabled = enableAll;
    txtadd1.Enabled = enableAll;
    txtadd2.Enabled = enableAll;
    txtadd3.Enabled = enableAll;
    ddlCountry.Enabled = enableAll;
    check_desc.Enabled = enableAll;
    btnSaveExit.Enabled = enableAll;
    btnDelete.Enabled = enableAll;
    btnClear.Enabled = enableAll;
}
```

Keep in mind you can not have head and tail at the some time some options could not coexist like View and Delete in your case.

Comment: let me try and check with my Team members also

Comment: i guess if the value is `Y` it should enable it. but here in ur case its vice versa `if (dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
                    enableAll = false;` I guess it should be `true`

Comment: Check the code in your question for VIEW_FLAG == "Y" you are disabling all the control so I do? Now you may have to adjust the code as per your requirement as I already mentioned.

Comment: OK. I guess, I still need to tune this as some of the conditions are still not getting right..

Comment: :I have added some different logic to work. If you dont mind Shd I add this as an answer ? Also let me know whether it is ok to GO or no

Comment: You can add and mark your answer. Test it to set criteria to see if it meets the requirements.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Comment: is the answer OK to go ? or need some changes. you can add your comment if u feel that something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking through specific field in the `dtFill`. I assume you are looking for only 1 condition to be true. **UPDATE**: Used your original code. Quite Lengthy.

Try this:

```
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["ADD_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y" || dtFill.Rows[0]["MODIFY_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
            txtdesc.Enabled = true;
            txtadd1.Enabled = true;
            txtadd2.Enabled = true;
            txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
            check_desc.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["VIEW_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = false;
            txtdesc.Enabled = false;
            txtadd1.Enabled = false;
            txtadd2.Enabled = false;
            txtadd3.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = false;
            check_desc.Enabled = false;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = false;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtFill.Rows[0]["DEL_FLAG"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            txtAbbreviation.Enabled = true;
            txtdesc.Enabled = true;
            txtadd1.Enabled = true;
            txtadd2.Enabled = true;
            txtadd3.Enabled = true;
            ddlCountry.Enabled = true;
            check_desc.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveExit.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            btnClear.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: it just checks the first condition and throws out of the loop, that is incorrect I guess

Comment: Yea I just recently checked the comments for the sample database record. I'll revise this.